# Replace no result

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT TV.Descrizione as TipoVers, 
       sum(ImportoVersamento) as ImpTot, 
       count(*) as N,
       month(DataAllibramento) as Mese
FROM PROC_Versamento V
left outer join dbo.PROC_TipoVersamento TV
    on V.IDTipoVersamento = TV.IDTipoVersamento
inner join dbo.PROC_PraticaRiscossione PR 
    on V.IDPraticaRiscossioneAssociata = PR.IDPratica
inner join dbo.DA_Avviso A
    on PR.IDDatiAvviso = A.IDAvviso
where DataAllibramento between '2012-09-08' and '2012-09-17' and  A.IDFornitura = 4
group by V.IDTipoVersamento,month(DataAllibramento),TV.Descrizione
order by V.IDTipoVersamento,month(DataAllibramento)
```

This query *must* always return something. If no result is produced a

```
0 0 0 0
```

row must be returned. How can I do this. Use a *isnull* for every selected field isn't usefull.

Comment: Kinfly provide the complete Query.

Comment: @Luv all code is reported now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a derived table with one row and do a outer apply to your other table / query.

Here is a sample with a table variable `@T` in place of your real table.

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int,
  Grp int
)

select isnull(Q.MaxID, 0) as MaxID,
       isnull(Q.C, 0) as C
from (select 1) as T(X)
  outer apply (
              -- Your query goes here
              select max(ID) as MaxID,
                     count(*) as C
              from @T
              group by Grp
              ) as Q
order by Q.C -- order by goes to the outer query
```

That will make sure you have always at least one row in the output.

Something like this using your query.

```
select isnull(Q.TipoVers, '0') as TipoVers, 
       isnull(Q.ImpTot, 0) as ImpTot, 
       isnull(Q.N, 0) as N,
       isnull(Q.Mese, 0) as Mese
from (select 1) as T(X)
  outer apply (
              SELECT TV.Descrizione as TipoVers, 
                     sum(ImportoVersamento) as ImpTot, 
                     count(*) as N,
                     month(DataAllibramento) as Mese,
                     V.IDTipoVersamento
              FROM PROC_Versamento V
              left outer join dbo.PROC_TipoVersamento TV
                  on V.IDTipoVersamento = TV.IDTipoVersamento
              inner join dbo.PROC_PraticaRiscossione PR 
                  on V.IDPraticaRiscossioneAssociata = PR.IDPratica
              inner join dbo.DA_Avviso A
                  on PR.IDDatiAvviso = A.IDAvviso
              where DataAllibramento between '2012-09-08' and '2012-09-17' and  A.IDFornitura = 4
              group by V.IDTipoVersamento,month(DataAllibramento),TV.Descrizione
              ) as Q
order by Q.IDTipoVersamento, Q.Mese
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'values'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: @marianoc84 What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @marianoc84 You are probably on SQL Server 2005. Try the updated version of the answer.

Comment: Perfect! I just replaced nullif with isnull! ;)

Comment: @marianoc84 Haha. that would certainly improve matters :)

Comment: @marianoc84 Don't really understand that. What values should there be on the rows? Why does it matter how many rows you get? You should probably ask that as a new question where you provide the table structures some sample data and the expected output. You could even setup a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to help the answerers along the way.

Comment: A disadvantage of doing things this way is that you assume the result set will never contain nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Use [COALESCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366488/coalesce-function-in-tsql). It returns the first non-null value. E.g.

```
SELECT COALESCE(TV.Desc, 0)...
```

Will return 0 if TV.DESC is NULL.

Comment: It doesn't works. Are we sure that no result is the same as NULL?

Comment: Well, that depends on the data in your database. You did mention using isnull, so I assumed there were some non-null values that you were checking against. What specifically are you considering "no result"? An empty string?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
with    dat as (select    TV.[Desc] as TipyDesc, sum(Import) as ToImp, count(*) as N, month(Date) as Mounth
                from        /*DATA SOURCE HERE*/ as TV
                group by    [Desc], month(Date))
    select    [TipyDesc], ToImp, N, Mounth from    dat
    union all
    select    '0', 0, 0, 0 where    (select count (*) from dat)=0
```

That should do what you want...

Comment: PS. I'm guessing that by 'No result', you mean that no rows were returned.

Answer (score -3):

If it's ok to include the "0 0 0 0" row in a result set that **has** data, you can use a union:

```
SELECT TV.Desc as TipyDesc, 
   sum(Import) as TotImp, 
   count(*) as N,
   month(Date) as Mounth
   ...
UNION
SELECT
    0,0,0,0
```

Depending on the database, you may need a FROM for the second SELECT.  In Oracle, this would be "FROM DUAL".  For MySQL, no FROM is necessary