# ERROR: COALESCE types timestamp without time zone and integer cannot be matched (Postgresql)

Tags: coalesce, postgresql-9.3

**## PROBLEM ##**

I got error from this script (**Postgresql 9.3.2**)
( It's OK in MS SQL Server )

```
SELECT 
 CASE COALESCE(my_date_field,0) 
 WHEN 0 THEN 0 
 ELSE 1 END 
 AS status
FROM 
 my_table
```

`Error :COALESCE types timestamp without time zone and integer cannot be matched`
`Line 2 : CASE COALESCE(my_date_field,0)`

**## SOLVED ##**

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN my_date_field IS NULL 
  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
  AS status
FROM 
  my_table
```

**COALESCE** accepts pretty much any number of parameters, but they should be the **same data-type**.
I quoted from [COALESCE Function in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366488/coalesce-function-in-tsql)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Zero is not a valid date. It's surprising that it works in MS SQL. You need to use a sensible date, or accept `NULL`.

```
 CASE COALESCE(my_date_field, DATE '0001-01-01')
```

The query is a bit bizarre in general. Isn't that an incredibly longwinded and complicated way of writing `IS NULL`?

```
SELECT 
 my_date_field IS NULL AS status
FROM 
 my_table
```

If, per comment, you want 0 or 1, use:

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN my_date_field IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS status
FROM 
 my_table
```

Comment: I just need to store 0 (if my_data_field is null) and 1 (if my_data_field is not null) in the new field 'status'