# sql compare fields with some nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

I"m trying to write a query in Oracle SQL to return rows if the value in field 1 does not equal the value in field 2 (where field2 includes some null values)

If the table looks like this

```
Field1    Field2
1         1
2         3
4
```

If I use this query:

```
select * from table where field1 != field2
```

I only get back row 2, but not row 3.  Is there a single query I can use to get both rows 2,3 retreived?

Comment: Orace uses three valued logic - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-jul/o45sql-097727.html

Comment: Do you want to include or exclude rows where both fields are null?

Comment: @mathguy exclude when they are both null, since they are effectively equivalent ( I know they are both null so we can't say that for sure but that is good enough)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also include if `field2` is `NULL`. You know the null isn't a match but want to show it.

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE field1 != field2
    OR (field1 IS NULL AND field2 IS NOT NULL)
    OR (field1 IS NOT NULL AND field2 IS NULL)
```

Additionally, you can use `COALESCE` to assert the `null` as another value. I used 0 in this case.  Only use 0 if there is no 0 for `field1` or `field2`. Basically choose a value that won't happen in your table.

```
select * from table where COALESCE(field1, 0) != COALESCE(field2, 0)
```

Edit: OP asserted that field1 could be null, so I changed the first query. Query 1 is a bit more clear on what's going on, and Query 2 is a more concise way to achieve the same end result.

Read more here: [COALESCE Function in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366488/coalesce-function-in-tsql)

You can also use `NVL()` to deal with `NULL` like `COALESCE`, however it is less efficient to my understanding.  More info: [Oracle Differences between NVL and Coalesce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce)

Comment: Thanks, I get that, but I'm wondering why this is necessary?  Isn't it unambiguously true that field1 doesn't = field2 if one of them is null?

Comment: It's nitpicky, but this doesn't handle the case when they are both NULL, or where field1 is NULL and field2 is not null. The COALESCE edit does though.

Comment: @Jonjilla I'm sure someone can answer this better... but `NULL` just not a value that can be compared. It's literally the absence of a value.  It's comparing something that exists vs something that is non-existent. Not comparing two things that exist.

Comment: The OP explained that a row should also be included if field1 is NULL but field2 is not, and a row should **not** be included if both fields are NULL. This solution includes a row if both fields are NULL, but excludes a row where field1 is NULL but field2 is not NULL. So, this does **not** solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @mathguy OP infers `field2` is the only field that contains `null`, so it essentially performs the same with or without `COALESCE` on `field1`. He also states "if the value in field 1 does not equal the value in field 2."

Comment: I asked the OP if he wants to show rows where **both** fields are NULL. He/she said "no, they should be considered equivalent so they shouldn't be included". I take it from this answer that in fact there may be NULL in field1 also.

Comment: @mathguy If both are `null` then `0 != 0` will not show.

Comment: Right; I meant my comment for the first solution only.

Comment: @mathguy Oh, yes, you're 100% right. I will edit when I can get to my computer or you can if you wish to. :D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *exclude* rows where both fields are `null` (as you indicated in a Comment), then you can use

```
select *
from   <table>
where  decode(field1, field2, 1, 0) = 0
;
```

This takes advantage of the peculiar definition of `decode`. It returns the third argument (1 in this example) if `field1 = field2` and ALSO when they are both `null` (contrary to the "proper" treatment of `null` in SQL). In all other cases it returns 0, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
  from table  
 where field1 != field2
    or (field1 IS NOT NULL AND field2 IS NULL)
    or (field1 IS NULL AND field2 IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi some correct answers here already but here is another one you may like better:

```
select * from table where field1 != nvl(field2,-field1);
```

Let us know if it works ok for you. For any further clarification don't hesitate to ask me again.

Ted

Comment: This solution is incorrect (considering the OP's definition of "not equal"). Indeed, if field1 is NULL but field2 is **not** NULL, then the row will not be included; however, the OP wanted it included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **case** statement to test equality in the reqiured sence. This expression never evaluates to null, so it is safe to apply **not** to over it and get the complementary rows.

```
select * from my_table
where 
not case 
  when field1=field2 then 1
  when field1 is null and field2 is null then 1
  else 0
end = 1;
```